# How to control password in asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have created a sign up form and I want to use the checkbox to `show` or `hide` password in the text box when checked and unchecked.

```js
Onchanged="document.getElementById('ID of the text box).type=this.checked ? 'text' : 'password'"
```

Comment: Your change should be in javascript, and not in C# or asp.net, since you don't want to postback and re-render the entire page. as such if should be onchange="someFunction()". the tags of the question should also be changed.

Comment: Alright, but i don't want to use JavaScript. How can that be possible. Thank you

Comment: JavaScript is the de-facto language for dynamically manipulating the browser behavior and altering the different html elements. I am afraid there's just no way to get around this.

Comment: Is this Blazor or Razor Pages? No? Then JavaScript is the way to go.

Comment: Alright, am new to it. So i have dig deeper . Thanks

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Password</td>
        <td><input type="password" id="txtPassword" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label for="chkShowPassword">
                <input id="chkShowPassword" type="checkbox" onclick="ShowPassword(this)" />
                Show password</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>


<script type="text/javascript">
    function ShowPassword(chkShowPassword) {

        var txtPassword = document.getElementById("txtPassword");
 
        //If CheckBox is Checked i.e. Password needs to be shown.
        if (chkShowPassword.checked) {
        txtPassword .setAttribute('type', 'text');
 
        } 
    else {
        txtPassword .setAttribute('type', 'password');
        }
    };
</script>
```